# Nested aggregate / group by

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this:

```
SELECT A.salesperson, A.TDP, A.Units, T.new_target as Target
FROM 
(
    SELECT a.new_salespersonidname as Salesperson, 
           a.new_salespersonid, 
           SUM(b.new_profits_sales_totaldealprofit) as TDP, 
           COUNT (a.new_dealsheetid) as Units 
    FROM new_dealsheet a 
        LEFT JOIN salesorder B ON a.new_dsheetid = B.salesorderid 
    WHERE MONTH(a.New_actualdate) = 7
      AND YEAR(a.new_actualdate) = 2016
      AND a.New_PassedToAdmin = 1 
    GROUP BY a.new_salespersonidname, a.new_salespersonid
) A 
LEFT JOIN new_salespersontarget T
    on  T.new_salespersonid = A.new_salespersonid
    AND T.new_month = 7 and T.new_year = 2016 AND T.new_type = 2
ORDER BY A.TDP desc
```

This works fine and gives me the total sales for a month (July 2016) along with the salespersons target for the month.

I need a second version of this which shows me all 2016. So I can easily change:

```
WHERE MONTH(a.New_actualdate) = 7 AND YEAR(a.new_actualdate) = 2016
```

to:

```
 WHERE YEAR(a.new_actualdate) = 2016
```

But, can I get the sum of all 2016 targets?

Thanks

Comment: Try using sum and group by in outer query....

Answer (score 0):

just group by

```
SELECT A.salesperson, sum(A.TDP) as TDP, sum(A.Units) as Units, T.new_target as Target
FROM 
....
LEFT JOIN new_salespersontarget T 
    on T.new_salespersonid = A.new_salespersonid 
        AND T.new_year = 2016 AND T.new_type = 2
GROUP BY A.salesperson, T.new_target
ORDER BY ...
```

Comment: You should to explain to the OP what you mean. Not only will it make the answer more clear but also useful to others who get confused why and where to use the GROUP BY.